# Interrupt safe "FIFO" for DSP on STM32 MCU

Tags: interrupt, stm32, race-condition, fifo, critical-section

I have an adc that reads values on an interrupt and stores them in a FIFO.

In the main programm I wanted to read the whole FIFO just like a regular array and do FFT and stuff. After a little bit of thinking I realized that the interrupt could occur during the reading process and that the data wouldn't be accurate anymore.

Can this be done without disabling the interrupt ?

I only found examples for push,pop FIFOs and although I could use one, I guess, I wanted to know if this is possible.

Here is my code:

```
#define SP_FIFO_SIZE 4096
#define SP_BITMASK_SIZE (SP_FIFO_SIZE - 1)

struct sp_fifo_struct{
    uint16_t array[SP_FIFO_SIZE];
    uint16_t pointer;
};

typedef volatile struct sp_fifo_struct sp_fifo;

void sp_fifo_push(sp_fifo * fifo, uint16_t value){
    fifo->array[fifo->pointer] = value;
    fifo->pointer = ((fifo->pointer + 1) & SP_BITMASK_SIZE);
}

void sp_fifo_read(sp_fifo * fifo, float32_t array[]){
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < SP_FIFO_SIZE; i++){
        array[i] = (float32_t) fifo->array[((fifo->pointer + i) & SP_BITMASK_SIZE)];
    }
}
```

Comment: If your handler is only filling the fifo and your thread only reading it, the resource (the array) is not really shared so you probably don't need to protect it with mutex or similar mechanism.

Comment: About the structure you propose `sp_fifo`I'm a bit surprised because  there are usually two indexes to manage a FIFO (on a embedded system without dynamic allocation), one for the next address/element to be written, one for the next element to be read.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean yes I knew that, but I thought I didn't need 2 pointer. Now I see why you need both in order to solve the interrupt problem.

I also don't quite understand how you can handle interrupts correctly. I know that you can handle multiple threads with, mutex, semaphores ect. but I don't know how that would work with interrupts because you can't really wait in an interrupt.

Comment: True. That's why I think you don't need mutex at all, but I'm not the best specialist of this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly need to mutex lock your fifo in this instance. This isn't the case *only* when you can guarantee atomic reads/writes of the data into the queue. Additionally, incrementing/decrementing your indexing variable *may or may not* be atomic depending on your hardware platform and datatype.

As far as the data processing, I don't know the format of your data, so it's hard to say. I assume you have fixed length data. If that's the case, your fifo could be a queue of structs (definition of your fixed length data) instead of individual bytes. This would ensure that read/writes of the queue are "atomic" in the sense that you are always grabbing one "data point" (however you define that).

Comment: I agree that, generally speaking, protecting a shared resource through mutex is an obvious and common practice but in this case of "producer/consumer" I am wondering if a mutex is really necessary ?

Comment: I've found this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: I implemented the standard FIFO with a read and write pointer and everthing works fine. My main programm is much faster then the interrupt so my FIFO is never full. And the wikipedia artikle also says that a FIFO is the best implementation for my type of Problem since I only have 1 Producer and 1 Consumer.

Answer (score 0):

nRF5 SDK from Nordic has a lock-free and interrupt safe FIFO, [Atomic FIFO](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsdk_nrf5_v17.1.0%2Flib_atfifo.html). It depends on [LDREXB and LDREXH](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289875835.htm) instructions.